# amp-story how to get mp4 video in amp-list full screen?

Tags: amp-html, amp-stories

I have an amp-story where I need to create a page with full-screen video from a dynamic generated url. In page-2 below where I use an amp-video component directly it renders full-screen, in page-3 where I use an amp-list to provide the video url it does not "fill" the page. See https://codepen.io/svdoever/pen/gKPdjK. To check out the example on codepen.io first click the button and refresh to enable the amp-story experiment. Then make the preview window large enough to show the story.

```
<!doctype html>
<html amp lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <script async src="https://cdn.ampproject.org/v0.js"></script>
    <script async custom-element="amp-story" src="https://cdn.ampproject.org/v0/amp-story-0.1.js"></script>
    <script async custom-element="amp-list" src="https://cdn.ampproject.org/v0/amp-list-0.1.js"></script>
    <script async custom-template="amp-mustache" src="https://cdn.ampproject.org/v0/amp-mustache-0.1.js"></script>
    <script async custom-element="amp-video" src="https://cdn.ampproject.org/v0/amp-video-0.1.js"></script>
    <title>My Story</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,minimum-scale=1,initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="canonical" href="amp-list-video-story.html">
    <style amp-boilerplate>body{-webkit-animation:-amp-start 8s steps(1,end) 0s 1 normal both;-moz-animation:-amp-start 8s steps(1,end) 0s 1 normal both;-ms-animation:-amp-start 8s steps(1,end) 0s 1 normal both;animation:-amp-start 8s steps(1,end) 0s 1 normal both}@-webkit-keyframes -amp-start{from{visibility:hidden}to{visibility:visible}}@-moz-keyframes -amp-start{from{visibility:hidden}to{visibility:visible}}@-ms-keyframes -amp-start{from{visibility:hidden}to{visibility:visible}}@-o-keyframes -amp-start{from{visibility:hidden}to{visibility:visible}}@keyframes -amp-start{from{visibility:hidden}to{visibility:visible}}</style><noscript><style amp-boilerplate>body{-webkit-animation:none;-moz-animation:none;-ms-animation:none;animation:none}</style></noscript>

    <style amp-custom>
        body {
            font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
        }

        amp-story-page {
            background: white;
        }

        h1 {
            font-size: 2.875em;
            font-weight: normal;
            line-height: 1.174;
            text-transform: uppercase;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <amp-story standalone>
        <amp-story-page id="cover">
            <amp-story-grid-layer template="vertical">
                <h1>Hello World</h1>
                <p>This is the cover page of this story.</p>
            </amp-story-grid-layer>
        </amp-story-page>

        <amp-story-page id="page-1">
            <amp-story-grid-layer template="vertical">
                <h1>Hello Earth</h1>
                <p>This is the earth page of this story.</p>
            </amp-story-grid-layer>
        </amp-story-page>


        <amp-story-page id="page-2">
            <amp-story-grid-layer template="fill">
                <amp-video width="480" height="270" 
                            src="https://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/gtv-videos-bucket/sample/WhatCarCanYouGetForAGrand.mp4" 
                            layout="responsive" 
                            poster="https://dummyimage.com/720x1280/000/fff" controls autoPlay loop>
                    <div fallback><p>Your browser doesn't support HTML5 video.</p></div>
                </amp-video>
            </amp-story-grid-layer />
            </amp-story-page>
          <amp-story-page id="page-3">
            <amp-story-grid-layer template="fill">
                <amp-list layout="fill" width="480" height="270" single-item items="."
                    src="https://gist.githubusercontent.com/svdoever/9de8228fbea47100cdac3ee636f04d3f/raw/4d2b98691858c2e780a489cb201ac0fe491b24c0/amp-list-video-story.json">
                    <template type="amp-mustache" id="amp-template-id">
                        <amp-video width="480" height="270" src="{{url}}" layout="responsive" poster="https://dummyimage.com/720x1280/000/fff" autoPlay>
                            <div fallback><p>Your browser doesn't support HTML5 video.</p></div>
                        </amp-video>
                    </template>
                </amp-list>
            </amp-story-grid-layer />
        </amp-story-page>

    </amp-story>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3):

Currently the "fill" styling (done with `object-fit: cover` on an element that takes up the full viewport) is only applied to direct descendants of `<amp-story-grid-layer>`, but your video is not a direct descendant because it is embedded within an `<amp-list>`.  You can see the styles causing this in [amp-story.css](https://github.com/ampproject/amphtml/blob/52b1e15c5e445783de68ab41bec6d8a114aaf39e/extensions/amp-story/0.1/amp-story.css#L243-L258).

That said, it is likely going to be a performance hit to do multiple roundtrip requests to determine the video to play (first to fetch the JSON, then to fetch the `poster`, then to fetch the `src`), and this will make the page appear blank until the network requests have completed.

Another approach that can be used is to determine the proper video URL server-side, to minimize the number of requests in the critical path for the user.

Comment: Jon, first of thanks for your great work on amp-story! My problem is that I need to display a youtube video, amp-youtube is not allowed so I created a service to get the mp4 url of a youtube video, but I need to get it dynamically from amp-page, and not on server, because url will expire. See my blogpost https://medium.com/@svdoever/convert-youtube-url-to-mp4-url-f371d9574b7. I can get all required data data (src, poster) in one call. Would be better if amp-youtube was supported in amp-story! I can't process the video (make it 1:1.77 aspect ratio).Does this mean that the problem is unsolvable?

Comment: I think the correct way is for the format to natively support `amp-youtube`, which is planned.  Until that happens, this won't work well.  As a side note, YouTube videos are generally (always?) landscape, so using them as full-bleed videos in a portrait container will cause cropping of almost 50% of the video.

Comment: amp-youtube support would be great! I know the video's are cropped, but in this case they serve more as a background and are an impression of a campsite.

Comment: Follow [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/ampproject/amphtml/issues/15847) for updates on supporting custom video players like `<amp-youtube>`.